# Save Values on Exit C++

Tags: c++, save

I've been working on a C++ program which gets values and saves them for later use. The problem for me is saving the data on exit, and initializing it on opening. How can I do this?

Comment: Store the data in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lib like [pugixml](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml) to easily write the data on a xml file and read it on program startup.

On linux, you can register a "program exiting" callback with the [atexit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/) function, this is the perfect place to put your xml creation code. There is probably something similar to the `atexit` function on windows :)

**Edit:**

Another alternative, like @molbdnilo said, is to leave the file writing code in the end of the main function, which would not require using global variables to hold the data that needs to be written.

Comment: It's much better to save as the last action in `main` than in an exit handler. It makes the program flow explicit, and if you save in an exit handler all the data you want to save must have static linkage (usually global variables).

Comment: @molbdnilo see my edit :)